# Adding more colors to vba excel

Tags: vba, excel, colors

This is my finished product for a search and highlight code, it works fine but i want to more colors to my code. I want another inputbox to pop up after 
`SearchString = InputBox(Prompt:="What word would you like to highlight?")`
asking what color you want the word highlight in.

```
Sub Sample()
Dim oRange As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ExitLoop As Boolean
Dim SearchString As String, Foundat As String
Dim iCount() As String
Dim outws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("detail_report")

Set oRange = ws.Cells


SearchString = InputBox(Prompt:="What word would you like to highlight?")

Set aCell = oRange.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    Set bCell = aCell
    Foundat = aCell.Address
    Do While ExitLoop = False
        Set aCell = oRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
            Foundat = Foundat & ", " & aCell.Address
        Else
            ExitLoop = True
        End If
    Loop

 iCount = Split(Foundat, ", ")

Set outws = Worksheets("output")
    outws.Range("A1").Value = "Word"
    outws.Range("B1").Value = "Count"
    outws.Range("A2").Value = SearchString
    outws.Range("B2").Value = UBound(iCount) + 1

   End If

 Dim cellRange As Range
 Set cellRange = oRange.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

 If Not cellRange Is Nothing Then


Foundat = cellRange.Address

Do

    Dim textStart As Integer
    textStart = 1

    Do

        textStart = InStr(textStart, LCase(cellRange.Value), LCase(SearchString))
        If textStart <> 0 Then
            cellRange.Characters(textStart, Len(SearchString)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            textStart = textStart + 1
        End If


    Loop Until textStart = 0


    Set cellRange = oRange.FindNext(After:=cellRange)

Loop Until cellRange Is Nothing Or cellRange.Address = Foundat
Else
    MsgBox SearchString & " not Found"


End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You could use the constants http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Application/VBADefinedConstantsvbRed.htm

Answer (score 1):

If I were you'd I'd create a custom control with a dropdown, in addition to your question "What word would you like to highlight". Instead of using two default InputBox prompts.

However, a quick and easier approach is to just set up another InputBox and ask for the color. Then use a 'switch case' statement to check for valid inputs. You could re-prompt the user if they entered a non-supported value, or just use a default.

```
'I like to use UCASE to standarize the case of the user's input
ColorString = UCASE(InputBox("What color would you like to use?"))

'Set Default Color
color = RGB(0,255,255)

select case ColorString
    case "RED"
         color = RGB(255,0,0)
    case "GREEN"
         color = RGB(0,255,0)
    case "BLUE"
         color = RGB(0,0,255)
end select
```

'Now set the cell when you find your matches in your previous algorithm

cellRange.Interior.Color = color

Comment: I get a compile error "assignment to constant not permitted" for color

Comment: you may want to change the variable names, this is just an example. I believe the word Color may be reserved.